# How to Fix class not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

In Laravel I need to communicate to a 3rd party API. Thay have given me some PHP implementation (class) which I can use to connect and communicate with their API. 
But when I try this as a class in a subfolder of the App folder and add this to my controller, I get a class not found error.

I have added a folder 'Qenner' (the provider of the API) in the App folder. And copied their classes in there.
In my controller I'm using these classes and add a code sample, like they send it to me.

Controller code (API-KEY is replaced with the actual key):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Qenner\Search;
use QennerSearch\ServiceClient;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $search = new Search('https://search.qenner.com', 'API-KEY', true, 'nl-NL');

$response = $search->getCriteria([], ['Country'], []);

if (!$response->isError()) {
  $criterionSets = $response->getCriterionSets();
  $countryCriterionSet = criterionSets[0];
  $countries = $countryCriterionSet->getCriteria();
  $resultCount = $response->getResultCount();
}
dd($response);
    }
```

Search.php in Qenner folder:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains QennerSearch\Search.
 */

namespace QennerSearch;

use QennerSearch\model\messages\CriterionTypesResponse;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\CriteriaRequest;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\CriteriaResponse;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\ErrorResponse;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\SearchRequest;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\SearchResponse;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\PriceRequest;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\PriceResponse;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\AccommodationInfoRequest;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\AccommodationInfoResponse;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\AutoCompleteRequest;
use QennerSearch\model\messages\AutoCompleteResponse;


/**
 * Class Search, using ServiceClient to communicate, implementing the SearchInterface
 *
 * @package QennerSearch
 */
class Search extends ServiceClient implements SearchInterface {
.....
```

The folder has a ServiceClient.php

ServiceClient.php

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains QennerSearch\Search.
 */

namespace QennerSearch;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

/**
 * Class Search.
 *
 * @package QennerSearch
 */
class ServiceClient {

    protected $http_client = null;
    protected $engine_url = null;
    protected $api_key = null;
    protected $log_calls = false;
    protected $locale = null;
    protected $last_result_code = 0;
    protected $last_error_body = null;

    public function __construct($engine_url, $api_key, $log_calls = false, $locale = "nl-NL") {
        $this->http_client = new Client();
        $this->engine_url = $engine_url;
        $this->api_key = $api_key;
        $this->log_calls = $log_calls;
        $this->locale = $locale;
```

I get this error:

Class 'QennerSearch\ServiceClient' not found

While I expected a dump of the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updated

After seeing your folder structure in the comments, I believe ServiceClient.php and Search.php, both are inside the folder: `app\Qenner`, hence inside those files:

wherever you are using: `namespace QennerSearch;`

you should use: `namespace App\Qenner;`

and then inside your controller, instead of using: `use QennerSearch\ServiceClient;`

use: `namespace App\Qenner\ServiceClient`

Namespaces are not like aliases, they need to reflect the position of the file itself if that makes sense.

Please give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Except for the controller, it is all from the 3rd party. I've added the first part of the ServiceClient.php code to the issue above. Seems like it's already added there

Comment: please paste your folder structure as well, where is which file, in which folders, ServiceClient.php and your controller

Comment: app\Http\Controllers\TestController.php
app\Qenner\Search.php
app\Qenner\ServiceClient.php

Comment: It worked thx, getting some other class not found messages now, but I'll try to solve them first myself :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) happy coding